# Connect to restlet from SuiteScript 2.0 NetSuite using oauth 2.0

Tags: oauth-2.0, netsuite, hmac, suitescript2.0, restlet-2.0

I am trying to connect to restlet from SuiteScript 2.1 using **oauth 1.0(TBA)*, but SuiteScript 2.1 crypto does not support hash. Is there any possible way we can achieve this?

We have used crypto and encode, but nothing works. Is there any other way in SuiteScript 2.1 or 2.0 to oauth 1.0(TBA) for encrypted authentication or to create a signature using HMAC-SHA256?

```
        var SIGNATURE_METHOD = "HMAC-SHA256"
        var length = 11;
        var OAUTH_NONCE = random(length)
        var date  =  new Date()
        var milliseconds = date.getTime()
        var TIME_STAMP = parseInt(((milliseconds -120000)/1000))

        var OAUTH_VERSION = "1.0";
        var SCRIPT_DEPLOYMENT_ID = 1;
        var REALM =  "78787878"
        var CONSUMERKEY = "4554545";
        var CONSUMERSECRET = "45455454";
        var TOKENKEY = "78787878";
        var TOKENSECRET = "4545454544";
        var base_url = "https://89898989-sb1.restlets.api.netsuite.com/app/site/hosting/restlet.nl"

        var encdata  = "deploy=" + SCRIPT_DEPLOYMENT_ID + "&"
        encdata = encdata + "oauth_consumer_key=" + CONSUMERKEY + "&"
        encdata = encdata + "oauth_nonce=" + OAUTH_NONCE + "&"
        encdata = encdata + "oauth_signature_method=" + SIGNATURE_METHOD + "&"
        encdata = encdata + "oauth_timestamp=" + TIME_STAMP + "&"
        encdata = encdata + "oauth_token=" + TOKENKEY + "&"
        encdata = encdata + "oauth_version=" + OAUTH_VERSION + "&"
        encdata = encdata + "script=" + scriptId

        var baseEncrypt = base_url;
        var encryptData = encdata;
        var completeData = method+'&' + baseEncrypt + '&'+  encryptData
        var ConsumerSecretEncode = CONSUMERSECRET
        var ConsumerTokedEncode = TOKENSECRET
        var key = ConsumerSecretEncode + "&" + ConsumerTokedEncode
        var algorithm = 'SHA256';

        var signatureNormal = generateHMAC(key, completeData, algorithm, crypto, encode);
        var signature = signatureNormal

        var OAuth = "OAuth realm=\"" + REALM + "\","
        OAuth = OAuth + "oauth_consumer_key=\"" + CONSUMERKEY + "\","
        OAuth = OAuth + "oauth_token=\"" + TOKENKEY + "\","
        OAuth = OAuth + "oauth_signature_method=\"HMAC-SHA256\","
        OAuth = OAuth + "oauth_timestamp=\"" + TIME_STAMP + "\","
        OAuth = OAuth + "oauth_nonce=\"" + OAUTH_NONCE + "\","
        OAuth = OAuth + "oauth_version=\"" + "1.0" + "\","
        OAuth = OAuth + "oauth_signature=\"" + signature + "\""
        return OAuth
}

function generateHMAC(key, data, algorithm, crypto, encode) {

        const encoder = encode
        const dataValue = encoder.convert({
            string: data,
            inputEncoding: encoder.Encoding.UTF_8, // Use the value directly
            outputEncoding: encoder.Encoding.BASE_64 // Use the value directly
        });
        const keyData = encoder.convert({
            string: key,
            inputEncoding: encoder.Encoding.UTF_8, // Use the value directly
            outputEncoding: encoder.Encoding.BASE_64 // Use the value directly
        });

        return crypto.subtle.importKey('raw', keyData, { name: 'HMAC', hash: 'SHA-256' }, false, ['sign'])
            .then((cryptoKey) => crypto.subtle.sign('HMAC', cryptoKey, dataValue))
            .then((signature) => {
                const view = new DataView(signature);
                let hash = '';
                for (let i = 0; i < view.byteLength; i++) {
                    const hex = view.getUint8(i).toString(16);
                    if (hex.length === 1) {
                        hash += '0';
                    }
                    hash += hex;
                }
                return hash;
            });
}
```

Comment: I am not sure but I think  you aren't using right approach for using OAuth2.0 for NetSuite. Please check NetSuite help. As per my knowledge you are currently using TBA authentication not oAuth2.0. In oAuth2.0 you have to first get the code, then generate the access token and resfresh token (resfresh token will expire in 7 days in NetSuite), then you can use refresh token again to generate access token as access token will expire in approx 1 hour.

Comment: @HiddenOne1254 Indeed, he is using the Oauth 1.0 but regarding OAuth 2.0, there is also the client credential flow that allow you to get an access token with a certificate without user interaction

Comment: @AnthoVdo : You are correct. I am trying to connect to restlet using Oauth 1.0 (TBA). But in suitescript 2.1  crypto does not support  SHA256 encryption. Is there any possible way.

Comment: @Sri for now, I guess that you need to use an external library like crypto.js

Comment: @AnthoVdo: It would be helpful. If you share some library reference. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Restlets are for **external** integrations. If you want to call a NetSuite script from within NetSuite client side use Suitelets which use the existing user session.

Comment: @AnthoVdo I was talking about Authorization grant.

Comment: If you are trying to call a restlet in the same account then you are better off using a suitelet. If you are trying to call a restlet in another account then what you are trying can be made to work.

Comment: You can generate an SHA256 HMAC in Netsuite. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46585524/suitescript-hmac-sha256

Comment: @bknights: I have a external suitelet where it get data from restlet. So now i am trying to create oauth 1.0 TBA to connect to restlet. But when i generate key and data to create hmac using SHA256. It shows me unexpected error in suitelet 2.1  `   var hmacHash = crypto.createHmac({algorithm: crypto.HashAlg.SHA256,key: key});

           hmacHash.update({input:completeData,inputEncoding:crypto.Encoding.UTF8});

var hmac = hmacHash.digest({outputEncoding: crypto.Encoding.BASE_64});`

Comment: so the question is why? If you are in a suitelet you can call the same code as is used by the RESTlet. However to make the RESTlet call did you review the link I posted above?

Comment: @bknights : That is a good idea. But we are trying to connect to different account. So I try doing the post have linked. But I am getting 'AN_ERROR_OCCURRED_WHILE_DECRYPT_PASSWORDGUID' . What should be guid value ?  Where we use this             var key = ConsumerSecretEncode + "&" + ConsumerTokedEncode
 to generate hmac